# The difference between the handle received in the WNDPROC window callback procedure vs the one returned by CreateWindow?

Tags: c++, winapi

So i was wondering if there is any difference between the handle returned when creating the window using `CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx`, and the one that is passed as a parameter to the `WNDPROC` window callback procedure for the concerned window. The context for this question is that I need to use certain API functions that require a handle to the window, so I thought that instead of passing the handle received by the window callback procedures, I could just save a copy of the handle returned by CreateWindow once, and then use it for successive operations, in case both handles are the same.

Regards,

Devjeet

Comment: Why don't you compare them? Also why don't you want to use the one received by the window callback procedure?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to, it's just that if something could be done without passing it, it would be better. The functions I use are made for one purpose only, and only one window procedure is gonna use it. So it thought it would also be simpler just to save the handle at once, without passing it all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful here, the window procedure is used by multiple instances of a window.  The callback is determined by the value of WNDCLASSEX.lpfnWndProc so any CreateWindow/Ex() call that uses the same window class name uses the same callback.  If you are doing this to map the callback to a class instance method then you first have to go through a thunk that maps the callback's *hwnd* argument to a class instance.  Making a special case for WM_CREATE of course.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they are the same, that's the whole point of having an HWND. Every window has only one `HWND` that identifies it within the system and remains valid until `DestroyWindow` is called with it. It is returned by `CreateWindow(EX)` and sent in with every message so you can use that as a unique identifier for your window, even if you create several windows of the same class.

But note that some messages are sent to the window procedure even before the `CreateFunction` returns, so if you use a global variable to hold your `HWND`:

```
HWND globalHwnd = NULL;

int main()
{
    //...
    globalHwnd = CreateWindow(...);
}

LRESULT WndProc(HWND hWnd, ...)
{
    assert(hWnd == globalHwnd); //fail!
}
```

The assertion will fail because several messages such as `WM_CREATE` are sent before `CreateWindow` returns, so the global variable is not yet assigned.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I'll be using it as a member of a class.